# Freezing certain cells - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about freezing certain cells. But first let me explain the situation.
I have made a search box in my excel sheet and when you search for a letter or word; the results show up in cells below the search box. Now I want to freeze those cells, so that wherever I go in my sheet. I can always use the search box and see the results.

The cells for the searchbox and results are B2:B25. Those are the ones I want to freeze. Also the only sheet I want to use this on is the sheet "Reading". On the rest of my sheets I do not use a search function.

So my question(s) is : Do I need to put the code inside a module or on that sheet, and how do I do this?

Now I have tried the following

```
Range(Cells(2,2), Cells(25, 2)).Select
ActiveWindow(or maybe Reading?).FreezePanes = True
```

Inside a module. But it did not work and I do not know what else to do.

Any help is much appreciated! Since I am very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Problem is that the 'range' and 'cells' needs to be directed to the 'Reading' sheet, like so:

```
Sheets("Reading").Range(Sheets("Reading").Cells(2,2), Sheets("Reading").Cells(25, 2)).Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

but if it always is B2->B25, why not use:

```
Sheets("Reading").Range("B2:B25").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

This should work. Select is not very desirable, because it is very slow, but in this case, you need to (as far as I know).

---

EDIT

---

BTW, you can do this from within a code module or from within a sheet, but if you choose to do it from within a sheet, you cannot select another sheet. So just use the range.

---

EDIT 2

---

whoopsy, typo corrected. 'Sheet' should have been 'Sheets'